# Get Javascript handle callback when closing Safari tab

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile-safari, dom-events

How I can get callback or event when Safari mobile tab is closed manually. pagehide and beforeunload and unload doesn't fire when Safari tab is closed. They are fired when page reload or navigation happens.

Comment: This reads like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): What are you trying to do when the tab closes?

Comment: I am trying to implement one mutex kind of variable(in localStorage) which will help me to make sure only one ui dialog box is opened across all the tabs in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.unload(deprecated) || document.pagehide
```

you can check that link for furthermore [apple safari developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Comment: The question explicitly rejects the two options you propose.